# Hmac verification with flask in Python (with reference in PHP and RUBY)

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, flask, hmac

I have been working on a way to implement HMAC verification in python with flask for the selly.gg merchant website.

So selly's dev documentation give these following examples to verify HMAC signatures (in PHP and ruby): https://developer.selly.gg/?php#signing-validating
(code below:)

PHP:

```
<?php
        $signature = hash_hmac('sha512', json_encode($_POST), $secret);
        if hash_equals($signature, $signatureFromHeader) {
            // Webhook is valid 
        }
?>
```

RUBY:

```
signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha512'), secret, payload.to_json)
is_valid_signature = ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(request.headers['X-Selly-Signature'], signature)
```

So, so far what I could figure out: They don't encode with base64 (like shopify and others do), it uses SHA-512, it encodes the secret code alongside json response data and finally the request header is 'X-Selly-Signature'

I've made the following code so far (based on shopify's code for HMAC signing https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/webhooks):

```
SECRET = "secretkeyhere"
def verify_webhook(data, hmac_header):
    digest = hmac.new(bytes(SECRET, 'ascii'), bytes(json.dumps(data), 'utf8'), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
    return hmac.compare_digest(digest, hmac_header)
try:
    responsebody = request.json #line:22
    status = responsebody['status']#line:25
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return not_found()
print("X Selly sign: " + request.headers.get('X-Selly-Signature'))
verified = verify_webhook(responsebody, request.headers.get('X-Selly-Signature'))
print(verified)
```

However selly has a webhook simulator, and even with the proper secret key and valid requests, the verify_webhook will always return False. I tried contacting Selly support, but they couldn't help me more than that

You can test the webhook simulator at the following address:
[https://selly.io/dashboard/{your](https://selly.io/dashboard/%7Byour) account}/developer/webhook/simulate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly right except that you don't need to `json.dumps` the request data. This will likely introduce changes into output, such as changes to formatting, that won't match the original data meaning the HMAC will fail.

E.g.

```
{"id":"fd87d909-fbfc-466c-964a-5478d5bc066a"}
```

is different to:

```
{
  "id":"fd87d909-fbfc-466c-964a-5478d5bc066a"
}
```

which is actually:

```
{x0ax20x20"id":"fd87d909-fbfc-466c-964a-5478d5bc066a"x0a}
```

A hash will be completely different for the two inputs.

See how `json.loads` and `json.dumps` will modify the formatting and therefore the hash:

```
http_data = b'''{
    "id":"fd87d909-fbfc-466c-964a-5478d5bc066a"
}
'''
print(http_data)
h = hashlib.sha512(http_data).hexdigest()
print(h)
py_dict = json.loads(http_data) # deserialise to Python dict
py_str = json.dumps(py_dict) # serialise to a Python str
py_bytes = json.dumps(py_dict).encode('utf-8') # encode to UTF-8 bytes
print(py_str)
h2 = hashlib.sha512(py_bytes).hexdigest()
print(h2)
```

Output:

```
b'{\n    "id":"fd87d909-fbfc-466c-964a-5478d5bc066a"\n}\n'
364325098....
{"id": "fd87d909-fbfc-466c-964a-5478d5bc066a"}
9664f687a....
```

It doesn't help that Selly's PHP example shows something similar. In fact, the Selly PHP example is useless as the data won't be form encoded anyway, so the data won't be in `$_POST`!

Here's my little Flask example:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

php_hash = "01e5335ed340ef3f211903f6c8b0e4ae34c585664da51066137a2a8aa02c2b90ca13da28622aa3948b9734eff65b13a099dd69f49203bc2d7ae60ebee9f5d858"
secret = "1234ABC".encode("ascii") # returns a byte object

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def selly():
    request_data = request.data # returns a byte object
    hm = hmac.new(secret, request_data, hashlib.sha512)
    sig = hm.hexdigest()

    resp = f"""req: {request_data}
    sig: {sig}
    match: {sig==php_hash}"""

    return Response(resp, mimetype='text/plain')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Note the use of `request.data` to get the raw byte input and the simple use of `encode` on the `secret` str to get the encoded bytes (instead of using the verbose `bytes()` instantiation).

This can be tested with:

```
curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:5000/" \
 -H 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' \
 -d "{\"id\":\"fd87d909-fbfc-466c-964a-5478d5bc066a\"}"
```

I also created a bit of PHP to validate both languages create the same result:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $post = file_get_contents('php://input');
    print $post;
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha512', $post, "1234ABC");
    print $signature;
?>
```